# Multiple critera lookup in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a way to find the highest date in column D where Customer = "Customer001", Work = "Service1" and Completed = "Yes". Any ideas on how to achieve this?

The sample spreadsheet can be seen here: http://goo.gl/CZYUOB

Customer    Work    Started Ended   Time    Completed
Customer001 Service1    14/08/2013 14.42.34 14/08/2013 15.02.10 0,33    Yes
Customer001 Service1    14/08/2013 13.58.03 14/08/2013 14.29.19 0,52    No
Customer003 Service1    14/08/2013 13.10.25 14/08/2013 13.57.40 0,79    yes
Customer002 Service3    14/08/2013 12.27.10 14/08/2013 13.09.25 0,70    No
Customer001 Service1    18/08/2013 16.00.21 18/08/2013 16.38.22 0,63    No
Customer001 Service1    15/08/2013 15.17.07 15/08/2013 16.17.03 1,00    yes

Comment: Programming language? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

DMAX(Database_arr, Field_str|num, Criteria_arr) 
Returns the highest value in a list or table of cells which fits your specified criteria.

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelcharts/ss/2010-06-19-excel-2010-sparklines-ovierview.htm